# Regular expression to match all but certain characters in class

Tags: ruby, regex

What's the best way match all punctuation characters in the class `[[:punct:]]` except `@` and `#`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
(?:(?![#\@])[[:punct:]])+
```

Comment: Thanks! You missed a "\" for @
This seems to work:
(?:(?![#\@])[[:punct:]])+

Comment: @primary0 What do you mean that Platinum missed a "\" for `@` ? I absolutely don't get it. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 1):

`[[:punct:]]` is equivalent to `` [!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~] ``

See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

You can simply extract the symbols you don't want:
`` [!"$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?[\]^_`{|}~] ``